# Get item in a list of list to compare to a value while iterate both lists Python

Tags: python, list, nested

I am now trying to implement connect-4 like questions, so I want to find out if there are any same `"X"`s or `"O"`s vertically, horizontally or diagonally. I turned the initial game board in to several nested lists in a list. 
like this:

```
[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', 'O', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', 'X', '.'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X']]
```

`'.'` stands for empty space and `'X'` and `'O'` stands for each players move.
Say I want to check if there were 3(I am implementing connect-3) same `"X"`s or `"O"`s diagonally. But I need to check each nested list, and the items on certain position in each nested list.
I have something like this:

```
#check positive-dia
for row in board:
    for col in board[row]:
        if(board[row][col] == "X" and board[row-1][col+1] == "X" and board[row-2][col+2] == "X"):
            print("X wins!")
        elif(board[row][col] == "O" and board[row-1][col+1] == "O" and board[row-2][col+2] == "O"):
            print("O wins!")
```

But I got the error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`.
I tried use sublist but I need to check every row too, so sublist doesn't work. 
I don't know what to do now.
Any hints will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables `row` and `col` are assigned by the `for` loop with the values of the items in the lists, not the indices of the lists. You should use the `range` generator instead if you want to make `row` and `col` indices:

```
for row in range(len(board)):
    for col in range(len(board[row])):
        if(board[row][col] == "X" and board[row-1][col+1] == "X" and board[row-2][col+2] == "X"):
            print("X wins!")
        elif(board[row][col] == "O" and board[row-1][col+1] == "O" and board[row-2][col+2] == "O"):
            print("O wins!")
```

Comment: thank you, I adjusted my code accordingly, now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without seeing the full stack trace and/or a [complete code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but this is probably because you're using an element of the list as an index into the list. For example, on the first pass through the outer loop (`for row in board:`), `row` is equal to the list `['.', '.', '.', '.', '.']`. You then have the expression `board[row]`, which tries to find the `['.', '.', '.', '.', '.']`th element of `board`. Naturally, Python complains about this, because it only make sense to find the 0th or 1st or 2nd (or so on) element of a list.

Probably the best way to proceed instead is to use an integer index, which you would get by making your loop like this:

```
for row_index in range(len(board)):
    # do something with board[row_index]
```

There are other ways to approach the problem in which you don't have to use an integer index, but those are probably a little more complicated for such a simple task.

Comment: thank you, I adjusted my code accordingly, now it works!